# How to sort notifications by dates in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm builing notifications component where I want to sort notification by dates and display them.

I tried but didn't work :

```
const result = notifications.notificationRows.sort((a, b) => b.time - a.time)
```

How can I do it over a following array ?

[image]

```
notificationRows: Array(25)
0:
notificationRow:
fee: "20 TEST"
id: "1.11.191431"
info: "[userlink=demo3], send 0.00021 TEST to ,[userlink=demo1]"
key: "1.11.191431"
time: "2022-05-17 16:54:21"
type: "transfer"
[[Prototype]]: Object
unread: false
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
notificationRow:
fee: "20 TEST"
id: "1.11.191430"
info: "[userlink=demo3], send 0.012 TEST to ,[userlink=demo1]"
key: "1.11.191430"
time: "2022-05-17 14:52:39"
type: "transfer"
[[Prototype]]: Object
unread: false
[[Prototype]]: Object
2:
notificationRow:
fee: "20 TEST"
id: "1.11.191427"
info: "[userlink=demo3], send 0.0021 TEST to ,[userlink=demo1]"
key: "1.11.191427"
time: "2022-05-17 14:34:15"
type: "transfer"
[[Prototype]]: Object
unread: false
```

My expected result is :

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an object array by date property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property)

Answer (score 0):

This does not works because you are comparing string instead of dates object. when you are trying to substract the two date in your sort function the result will always be `NaN`.

```js
"2022-02-01 12:00:00" - "2022-02-02 12:00:00" // NaN
```

You can use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object to compare and sort your object.

This will transform your string into `Date` object that can be compared as you did.

```js
new Date("2022-02-01 12:00:00") - new Date("2022-02-02 12:00:00") // -86400000 meaning the second date is after the first one
```

```js
const notifications = {
  notificationRows: [{time: '2022-02-01 12:00:00'}, {time: '2022-01-01 12:00:00'}, {time: '2022-03-01 12:00:00'}]
}

const oldResult = notifications.notificationRows.sort((a, b) => b.time - a.time)
console.log("Your result", oldResult)

const result = notifications.notificationRows.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.time) - new Date(a.time))
console.log("New result", result)
```